# Customize circled numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

[Below is one solution (by @Stefan)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/48787) for *circled numbers* with the help of `tikz`. What can I do to make it such that I can in-place customize its draw color, fill color, text color, etc.?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
    \circled{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not `tikz`, but here's an answer using the picture environment for the same question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460946/87678

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using `tikzmark` here because this amazing library detects which mode (text vs. math mode, if math mode, which) you are in, so you won't have to care about this. And I would like to argue that one should specify the line width in relative units such that it scales with the font size. Of course, you have all the possibilities to color stuff and so on. (The best part is that you can connect the nodes in paths and so on.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{mycircled/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0.1em,line width=0.04em}}
\begin{document}
abc \tikzmarknode[mycircled,draw=red]{t1}{d} 
{\Huge \tikzmarknode[mycircled,draw=blue,text=purple]{t1}{D}}
\[
\int\limits_{\tikzmarknode[mycircled,red]{a1}{a}}^{\tikzmarknode[mycircled,blue]{b1}{b}}
 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(\tikzmarknode[mycircled,red]{a2}{a})-
 F(\tikzmarknode[mycircled,blue]{b2}{b})
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[latex-latex,red] (a1) to[bend right] (a2);
 \draw[latex-latex,blue] (b1) to[bend left] (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The Ti*k*Z Wizard at work!

Comment: @marmot Why can't I compile your code?

Comment: @blackened Probably because you have not the most recent version of `tikzmark`. `\tikzmarknode` was added last June or so. You may have to update your TeX installation.

Comment: @user121799 Thank you for your solution. This is out of topic, but in the formula you should write ```F(b)-F(a)```.

Answer (score 10):

Edit after @marmot's (kind :P) comment (thanks):

This answer REALLY takes some care about a somehow constant size for all letters but not when `line width` is increased/decreased, because I had to set this parameter as extra or make some hacks in the way that it will be provided to my macro and I am not really sure if the OP need to change the line width (I just gave it initally as an idea about improving the appearance.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\mylength}
\xdef\CircleFactor{1.1}
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr\f@size pt}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand*\circled[2][draw=blue]{\savebox\mybox{\vbox{\vphantom{WL1/}#1}}\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr\CircleFactor\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox\relax\relax}\tikzset{mystyle/.style={circle,#1,minimum height={\mylength}}}
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
\node[mystyle] (char) {#2};}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This answer takes care of the current font size in a way that \circled{i} and \circled{W} will appear the same size here and in the next paragpaph with a \verb|\tiny| (or whatever font).

\noindent Demonstration:\\
\circled{i}\circled{i}\circled{W}\circled{W}\\
\circled{W}\circled{W}\circled{i}\circled{i}

\tiny This answer takes care of the current font size in a way that \circled{i} and \circled{W} will appear the same size here and in the this with a \verb|\tiny| (or whatever font).

\noindent Demonstration:\\
\noindent\circled{i}\circled{i}\circled{W}\circled{W}\\
\circled{W}\circled{W}\circled{i}\circled{i}

\normalsize Also you can give a parameter inside an optional argument of the command and have different appearance:

\circled[text=blue,fill=red,draw=black]{W}\circled[fill=yellow,draw=red,text=blue]{W}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the **old answer that DOESN'T REALY take care for the size** according to my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392188/120578).

You will select the style and could add your preferred style inside the optional argument of the definition of the command (I just placed the `draw=blue` option)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\def\mfontsize{\f@size}
\newcommand*\circled[2][draw=blue]{\tikzset{mystyle/.style={circle,#1,minimum height={\mfontsize*1.4}}}\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
{
    \node[mystyle] (char) {\vphantom{WAH1g}#2};}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is \circled{a} \circled[text=blue,fill=orange,draw=red, line width=0.3mm]{1} balloon.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Takes care of the size. Really? Try `\begin{document}
\noindent\circled{i} 

\noindent\circled{w} 

\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot: Possibly it was a lie... :P. If it was for "real" your example would not fail. (Thanks... kidding because this "Really?" heard funny to me. Edited).

Answer (score 8):

You can add more parameters to the command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\newcommand*\circled[4]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, fill=#2, draw=#3, text=#4, inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
    \circled{1}{red}{green}{blue}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You can also specify default values for the colors using `\NewDocumentCommand` from the `xparse` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\circleddefaults}{
    O{black}
    O{yellow}
    O{orange}
    m
    }{
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, fill=#1, draw=#2, text=#3, inner sep=2pt] (char) {#4};}}

\newcommand*\circled[4]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, fill=#2, draw=#3, text=#4, inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
    \circled{1}{red}{green}{blue}

    \circleddefaults[blue,brown]{2} % two colors specified, third default

    \circleddefaults{3} % all defaults
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here there is a minimal proposal hoping to have understood your request.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, fill= red, draw=yellow, inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
    \circled{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to be able to change the style when I use it.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it is necessary to change the excellent macro according to your needs with a new command. It depends on what you need. Have you looked at TikZ's manual?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a "double" customization that defines :

- an optional parameter of `\circled` that can be any style applied to the node,
- an optional `every number` style that, if defined, is applied to all circled numbers.

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,#1,every number/.try] (char) {#2};}}
\tikzstyle{every number}=[draw=red] % I like to use tikzstyle ;)
\begin{document}
    \circled{1}\circled[fill=yellow]{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]