# Letter in solid filled circle

Tags: letters, circles

One of my coauthors wants to typeset a letter that is inside a solid filled circle. I went through various symbol lists of packages, yet without luck. I am not sure if my memory is doing a trick on me, but I am sure I have seen it in publications.

Here is also an image of the desired result.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a package for just that: `circledsteps`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\newcommand\myCircled[2][]{\ifmmode
\Circled[fill color=black,inner color=white,#1]{\mathsf{#2}}
\else
\Circled[fill color=black,inner color=white,#1]{\sffamily#2}
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize A \myCircled{B} C

\footnotesize A \myCircled{B} C

\normalsize A \myCircled{B} C

\large A \myCircled{B} C

\Large A \myCircled{B} C

${\scriptstyle A \myCircled{B} C}$

$A \myCircled{B} C$

$A \myCircled{B} C_{{A \myCircled{B} C}_{A \myCircled{B} C}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really good, thanks a lot. Could you give me a hint on how to move the letter to the right in the circle. The documentation was not too helpful.

Comment: @SimonT. You can add horizontal space in the circle, e.g. `\newcommand\myCircled[2][]{\ifmmode
\Circled[fill color=black,inner color=white,#1]{\mathsf{~\mathstrut#2}}
\else
\Circled[fill color=black,inner color=white,#1]{\sffamily~\strut#2}
\fi
}`.

Comment: Technically it works, yet it makes the circle bigger, which is an undesired side effect. Do you maybe have another idea?

Comment: @SimonT. Yes. You can reduce the `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`, and then add some space along the lines of the above suggestion. Something like `\newcommand\myCircled[2][]{\ifmmode
\Circled[fill color=black,inner color=white,inner xsep=0.2ex,inner
ysep=0.5ex,#1]{\mathsf{\:#2}}
\else
\Circled[fill color=black,inner color=white,inner xsep=0.2ex,inner
ysep=0.5ex,#1]{\sffamily\:#2}
\fi
}`

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution with `TiKz`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
pics/mycirc/.style args={#1}{
      code = {
\node [draw, circle,fill] {\color{white}#1};
}}}
\begin{document}
This is \tikz [anchor=base,baseline] \pic {mycirc=B}; as mycircle.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, just this is a duplicate of the comment of @campa. :-) My greetings.

Answer (score 3):

With XeTeX and LuaTeX, you can directly input  (Unicode U+1F151) as long as your font includes this symbol ([Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/) is quite good IMHO):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\nicetest{Quivira}
\begin{document}
%\char"1F151\relax
{\nicetest }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, neither XeTeX nor LuaTeX are an option. I would also like to work Unicode free.

Comment: @SimonT. This may help, using letters instead of numbers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481168/customize-circled-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @SimonT. then your options are probably only tikz based using circular nodes filled with white text.