# Enumerate with circles and different colors

Tags: color, enumerate

I'm trying without success to use an enumeration with circled numbers but with different colors for each item:
[image]

Could you help me please?

Comment: Related: [Customize circled numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481168/5764)

Answer (score 4):

This is something that creates such colored lists. Ultimately you probably want to combine this with `enumitem`, but as you do not provide any code, here is a very basic version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/enumerate colors/.initial={"red","green!70!black","blue","orange","cyan",
    "magenta","teal","purple"}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{dim({\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/enumerate colors}})}%
\ifnum\value{enumi}>\mydim
\textsf{\arabic{enumi}}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/enumerate colors}}[\value{enumi}-1]}%
\Circled[inner color=white,fill color=\mycolor,outer color=\mycolor]{\textsf{\arabic{enumi}}}%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The colors are stored in the key `/csteps/enumerate colors`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my document is a huge document so I did not put my code. I will try your solution, I have an error with other enumerate blocks now

Comment: Your code works but (1) it changes all my other enumerate blocks and (2) there is a conflict with my style

Comment: @SébastienMailfert My crystal ball broke, so I didn't know what your code loads. As you say, my code works. If you want to have a more specific answer, you probably want to make your question more specific by adding a minimal example others can build on.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the colors, as shown in the MWE.  If you exceed 9 enumeration items, you will exceed the circle (bullet) diameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,enumitem}
\newcommand\circnum[1]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.1ex}{\small\textcolor{white}{#1}}%
  {\abovebaseline[-.7ex]{\Huge\textcolor{\csname colenum#1\endcsname}{$\bullet$}}}}
\csdef{colenum1}{red}
\csdef{colenum2}{blue}
\csdef{colenum3}{cyan}
\csdef{colenum4}{orange}
\csdef{colenum5}{green!70!black}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circnum{\theenumi}]
\item first
\item next
\item third
\item fourth
\item last
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is fully compatible with multiple enumeration instances and with all of my other packages. Thank you for your quick and precise answer

Comment: I will just change the size of the items and put my own specific colors and this will be OK!

Comment: @SébastienMailfert I'm glad you can make it work for you.