# Enumerate with options in items

Tags: enumerate, circles

I want an enumerated list where each number must be white circled on a coloured background. The background color must be passed as an option to each item in the list, without excluding color repetitions.
The code has to be something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[color1] Text
        \item[color1] Text
        \item[color2] Text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated : amsfonts is autoloaded by amssymb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from my answer here, [Enumerate with circles and different colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590834/enumerate-with-circles-and-different-colors/590844#590844).  The default color, if not specified, is black.

See **ADDENDUM** to provide two-digit capacity, per OP request.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\newcommand\circnum[2]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.1ex}{\small\textcolor{white}{#2}}%
  {\abovebaseline[-.7ex]{\Huge\textcolor{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}
\newenvironment{myenum}
{\let\svitem\item
 \renewcommand\item[1][black]{%
   \refstepcounter{enumi}\svitem[\circnum{##1}{\theenumi}]}%
\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenum}
\item[red] first
\item[blue] next
\item[cyan] third
\item fourth
\item last
\end{myenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,graphicx}
\newcommand\circnum[2]{\smash{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2ex}{\small\textcolor{white}{#2}}%
  {\abovebaseline[-1.43ex]{\Huge\textcolor{#1}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\bullet$}}}}}}
\newenvironment{myenum}
{\let\svitem\item
 \renewcommand\item[1][black]{%
   \refstepcounter{enumi}\svitem[\circnum{##1}{\theenumi}]}%
\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenum}
\item[red] first
\item[blue] next
\item[cyan] third
\item fourth
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item[purple] last
\end{myenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. If you can do a further update: make larger circles that also fit numbers with multiple digits.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Please see edited **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer for your request.

Comment: Thank you! this is better for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following also builds on [Enumerate with circles and different colors](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/590844/5764), updating the first level of `enumerate` to use a new `\item`, where the optional argument specifies the colour. If you don't supply an optional argument, the default configuration is used. This allows you to use the same `enumerate` environment for a coloured-`\item` list or not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,enumitem}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590844/5764
\newcommand\circnum[1]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.1ex}{\small\textcolor{white}{#1}}%
  {\abovebaseline[-.7ex]{\Huge\textcolor{enumicol}{\textbullet}}}}

\newcommand{\updateitem}{%
  \let\olditem\item% Store \item in \olditem
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/5764
    \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
      % No optional argument supplied to \item
      \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi.}% Default
    \else
      \colorlet{enumicol}{##1}% Update current circle label colour
      \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\circnum{\theenumi}}% Set label as a circled number
    \fi
    \olditem% Call original \item
  }
}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{before=\updateitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[red] first
  \item[green] next
  \item[blue] third
  \item[black!50] fourth
  \item last
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```